# Return multiple value from a method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Good Day I have a problem.

So I want to return a multiple value from the method below is my code:

```
public static String getReferee(String referee_id, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_referee", null);
    String refereeInfo = null;
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String nameInRecord = cursor.getString(1);

                if (nameInRecord.equals(referee_id))
                {
                    String referee_name = cursor.getString(0);        // 0 means table column of REFEREE NAME
                    String referee_game1 = cursor.getString(2);       // 2 means table column of REFEREE GAME 1
                    String referee_game2 = cursor.getString(3);       // 3 means table column of REFEREE GAME 2
                    refereeInfo = referee_name + referee_game1 + referee_game2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return refereeInfo1,refereeInfo2,refereeInfo3,refereeInfo4;
}
```

so as you can see the return code returns only the string refereeInfo which has a multiple data coming from my query. How can I do to return multiple String and pass it to my Main Activity.

Below code is my Main Activity:

```
 //GET REFEREE PROFILE
private void getRefereeProfile()
{
    String memberInfo = SQLiteFunctionUtility.getReferee(referee_id, mDbHelper.getSqliteObjectWithReadable());
    if (memberInfo != null)
    {
        txtview1.setText(returnstatement1);
        txtview2.setText(returnstatement2);
        txtview3.setText(returnstatement3);
        txtview4.setText(returnstatement4);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Referee Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I Search everything from the web and I'm badly need the answer. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Why don't you create an object, that holds the 4 values, and return it ?

Comment: using String array?

Comment: create an ArrayList object and set all value to that object and return object

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't no how to do that. I'm just a beginner. can you provide me an example codes. thank you.

Comment: I have posted the answer using ArrayList. Do check @RaphaelMendoza and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: For the specific case of 2 values, there's a `Pair` class in `android.support.v4.util`. That obviously won't work with 4 values, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to return multiple values, you need to put them into one object and return that one. You could use a `List` or `String[]`, but it would be more explicit to use a custom class for this pupose:

```
public static class Referee
{
    private String name;
    private String game1;
    private String game2;

    public Referee(String name, String game1, String game2)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.game1 = game1;
        this.game2 = game2;
    }

    // Getters...
}

public static Referee getReferee(String referee_id, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_referee", null);
    String refereeInfo = null;
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String nameInRecord = cursor.getString(1);

                if (nameInRecord.equals(referee_id))
                {
                    String referee_name = cursor.getString(0);  // 0 means table column of REFEREE NAME
                    String referee_game1 = cursor.getString(2); // 2 means table column of REFEREE GAME 1
                    String referee_game2 = cursor.getString(3); // 3 means table column of REFEREE GAME 2
                    return new Referee(referee_name, referee_game1, referee_game2);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you have a method called `getReferee`, it is a good indicator that you also should have a type `Referee` that is returned by that method. This way, your code becomes self-explanatory.

You can use the new type in your main activity like this:

```
private void getRefereeProfile()
{
    Referee memberInfo = SQLiteFunctionUtility.getReferee(referee_id, mDbHelper.getSqliteObjectWithReadable());
    if (memberInfo != null)
    {
        txtview1.setText(memberInfo.getName());
        txtview2.setText(memberInfo.getGame1());
        txtview3.setText(memberInfo.getGame2());
        // what is txtView4 for?
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Referee Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Malte Hartwig,
there is a error in your code,
in the line of:
return new Referee(referee_name, referee_game1, referee_game2);

it gives me an error "cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @RaphaelMendoza You can either put `Referee` in a new separate java file, or add `static` to its definition (I am going to add it to my answer).

Comment: And now my problem is how to call it through my main activity? sorry Newbie here.

Comment: the second code in my question is my main activity.

Comment: @RaphaelMendoza I added an example. Don't forget to add [getters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java syntax as you provided. What you can do is to create a wrapper object which will hold all values you want to return, and return it as one object.

Alternatively, you can use `ArrayList` or java array object.

Answer (score 0):

make one pojo class that define all the values and make method for database like this way..

```
public User getUser(String email, String password) {
    User user = new User();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Reg_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email=" + email + " AND password=" + password;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            user.email = (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
            user.password = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password")));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return user;
}
```

after that getting user data you can show email and password.

make one data base class that perform all operations.

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDb";
public static final String Reg_TABLE_NAME = "Register";

public Context mContext;

public DB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + Reg_TABLE_NAME + " (id integer primary key, email text, password text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Reg_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public User insertUser(User user) {
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("email", user.getEmail());
    contentValues.put("password", user.getPassword());
    long insertId = db.insert(Reg_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteComment(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Reg_TABLE_NAME, "id =" + id, null);
    db.close();
}

public User getUser(String email, String password) {
    User user = new User();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Reg_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email=" + email + " AND password=" + password;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            user.email = (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
            user.password = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password")));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return user;
}
}
```

and after that perform insert,update,read,delete like this way into activity and fragment..

```
        DB db=new DB(this); // if fragment then pass getActivity()
    User user=new User();
    user.setEmail("sdf");
    user.setPassword("sdf");
    db.insertUser(user);
```

Comment: Your answer is very simple and I want to implement it but how? can you do it with my actual code?

Comment: i update my answer and provide some code for hint but you can change according your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple values from a method in Java. There is no syntax to return multiple string as done by you. You can either use String Builder, Buffer or Array list to do this job.

If you are using array list do this:-

```
ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add(refereeInfo1);
arr.add(refereeInfo2);
arr.add(refereeInfo3);
arr.add(refereeInfo4);
```

And then you can return this list as:-

```
return arr;
```

Also change the return type of method from String to List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples - collections of anonymous/unrelated elements. Read this article http://www.baeldung.com/java-tuples. AFAIK Android sdk contains Pair tuple. Kotlin language have Pair and Triple. If you want you can write your own tuple with N parameters where 0 < N < 255